# What can I do about wall lights that are always on because they have no switch?

Tags: electrical

Older home with CONCRETE walls, last owners removed all lights. :-(

Husband wired sconces (that have no on/off switches) with E12 chandelier bulbs to wall and found there is no outlet or switch to turn them off manually. Wires are live-- likely wired originally to lights with switches.
Found a E12 chandelier to standard E26 socket...but no direct E12 socket that has a turn- knob or pull chain. Cobbling together another standard socket with turn- switch makes the contraption too large for the sconces.

Short of ditching the great sconces or re-wiring...any other alternatives?

Should I focus on replacing/ modifying the wall mounting plate?

[image]

Comment: Pic of the sconces? It’s not rocket surgery to change the lampholder to an e26.

Comment: What kind of boxes are these mounted on?

Comment: Is that sconce on the same wall as the switch behind it? Looks like the angles are all wrong... It's likely that either these were designed for security/night lights (without switches), or that something else very odd is going on, like there's a switch somewhere else. This might be the time to hire an electrician to trace the wires in the walls to ensure that there isn't a switch that you just haven't found.

Answer (score 4):

- You could drill a hole in the sconce's canopy and install a pull switch

  [image]
- You could look inside the boxes of all nearby wall switches for wires that are permanently nutted together and possibly were for a switch
- You could install smart bulbs in those sconces, and battery-powered wire-free smart switches on the wall.  *In fact a permanently powered fixture is an asset for this.*
- You (or an electrician) could install a regular wall switch in the wall near (within about 2 feet of) each sconce, very easily if directly below it.
- Ok this is ugly but you could buy switched socket extenders

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the wires run direct from the sconce to the electrical panel, and there's nothing else on that circuit, you can put a wireless switch on the wall, with the receiver in your panel driving that circuit.

Maybe you could also put receivers in the sconces, but then you need one per sconce.

With wireless light switches, the problem is having too much choice! There's so many of them. So make sure you plan ahead, for example if you need a receiver to work with several wall switches make sure it supports it.

You could also knock on the wall near the doors at switch height. Maybe there were switches that were removed, but you can still find the junction boxes and put switches back in. A wire detector/wall scanner may help.

Comment: Great answer! Two remarks though. I love the idea of smart switches, but then with smart bulbs, that makes it super easy.

Maybe an existing box has the wiring for these lamps in it too. Maybe a double switch can be used in the box in the picture. I would check that too.